# How to get last sunday's date from today's date using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to print the date of last Sunday by taking today's date as input for all days of the week except Sunday, but if it is Sunday then it should print today's date.  I tried this,

```
a=`date -dlast-sunday +%Y%m%d`
```

but this gives a date of Sunday before the last one.

Comment: Gives me the date of the 26 which is last sunday

Comment: Also note, use `$(...)` for command substitution rather than the antiquated backticks. It makes your script much more readable.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of asking for last Sunday, ask for one week before *next* Sunday.

```
$ date +%Y%m%d
20190531
$ date -d'next sunday - 1 week' +%Y%m%d
20190526
```

Just as "last Sunday" is always earlier than the current day, so is "next Sunday" always *after* the current day.

As it is Friday as I write this answer, let's ask for last Friday using this technique:

```
$ date +"%A %F"
Friday 2019-05-31
$ date -d 'next Friday - 1 week' +"%A %F"
Friday 2019-05-31
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that simply with the `date` command itself using the `date -d` option where:

```
date -d "today - $(date -d today +"%u") days"
```

Where you would pass whatever date you like as `today` (which is used as an example) and it will give the date of the previous Sunday. It does so by subtracting the current day of the week (`date -d today +"%u"`) number of days from the given date (`today` in the example). You can use an `if` before checking `if [ "$(date -d today +"%u")" -eq '7' ]; then date; else ... fi` to simply output the current date if today is Sunday.

**Example**

```
$ date -d "today - $(date -d today +"%u") days"
Sun May 26 23:04:44 CDT 2019
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
cal |
awk -v dat=$(date +%d) '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i==dat){
      if(i!=1){
         print "Last Sunday is: "$1
      }
      else{
         print "This day itself is Sunday."
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: With Kubuntu I have to add `-h` to turn off highlighting of today with `cal`.

Comment: @Cyrus, sure thanks sir for sharing; feel free to edit my post with your findings please, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The command to print the date of last Sunday by taking today's date is :

```
a=$(date -d 'last Sunday ' +"%A %F")
echo $a
```